# Word Guessing Game

Tags: python-3.x

I need help with fixing my code here is my code, my problem is that the lives in the game don't work properly, the code takes off lives when you get a guess right and the game ends when there are still multiple lives left(Im using python):

```
import random

with open("../Coding.txt") as word_file:
    words = word_file.read().split()

lives = 9

random_word = random.choice(words)
word_len = len(random_word)
guess = ""
attempt = 0
enter = ""
temp = "_" * word_len

lives = 9

print (temp)
for i in range(0,9):
    attempt +=1
    guess = input("Attempt no. "+str(attempt)+":")
    if guess in random_word and guess != enter:
        for i in range(0, word_len):
            if guess == random_word[i]:
                temp = temp[:i] + guess +temp[i+1:]
                print(temp)
                lives + 1
    if guess not in random_word:
            lives -= 1
            print("You have " +str(lives),"lives left")




if "_" not in temp:
        print("Congratulations, You guessed the word")
else:
    print("You ran out of lives please try again!")


enter code here
```

Comment: Use `pdb` or another debugger, or add `print` statements throughout your code to understand what it is doing. Debugging is a critical part of programming and we're not going to rob you of this great opportunity to learn it.

Comment: Also, you may find this program easier if you deal wth a list of characters, instead of actual strings, as lists are mutable. Then use `''.join(letter_list)` to make a string to print.